# How to receive messages from azure queue subscription using go

Tags: azure, go, azure-servicebus-queues

I trying to pull messages from azure service bus queue using Go.Queue topic name,subscription name,service name and shared access key value are the credentials.I'm not getting proper sample code for this.Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from azure.servicebus.control_client 
import ServiceBusService
bus_service=ServiceBusService(service_namespace='<namespace>', 
           shared_access_key_name='<key_name>',
           shared_access_key_value='<acess_key>')
topic_name = "<topic_name>" 
subscription_name = "<subscription_name>" 
message = bus_service.receive_subscription_message(topic_name, 
          subscription_name, peek_lock=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Go Cloud Development Kit Pub/Sub API is still a work in progress (it's one of our newer APIs). As of 2019-01-30, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/google/go-cloud/pull/1207) out for review that adds support, so stay tuned!

Comment: just used python azure.servicebus.control_client and fetch data from azure